# Ubuntu-server 19.10 image for Raspberry Pi 4 4GB

Tags: server, raspberrypi

How will we know that the ubuntu-server image for the Raspberry Pi 4 platform has been refreshed? It is not apparent from the naming convention. Is there a simple way to determine if the image was refreshed after November 1, 2019 since the earlier image does not boot completely on a RPi4 4GB board? I understand that there is a workaround (by limiting the memory allocation) and Hui Wang has provided a fix for slipstreaming.

When will a revised image be published (if not done so already)? Thanks.

Fully certified "newbie" on the subject and therefore if someone would be kind enough to indulge a little bit, I would appreciate it sincerely.

Comment: Usually I tell an ISO from the date found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (*easiest post-install/expansion, if compressed I'd peek in `/.disk/info` for the date of ISO*). Otherwise I look at MD5sum/checksum comparing it to the latest (beyond date of file; which I don't change).   This applies to ISO files, I don't have any recent r.pi images to check they are identical.

Comment: Yes, it is very difficult to have a naming convention for the image. And, also expect to have history of checksum values posted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in last comment, but main (official) releases are always published with a text file containing checksums; these remain available back to 4.10 (2004-October release). Flavors or 'community' based releases aren't as easy to find (less consistent), and 'daily' images are not kept once re-spun (note: 'daily' refers even if ISO is not created daily [eg. weekly]).  All architectures are treated equal so format same be it pi/sbc through pc (x86_64) or mainframe (s390).

Comment: The original question was for a specific "official" image. My apologies for being cryptic. Also, don't want to sound like a jerk but the checksum for the specific family of images uses SHA256 and there is only value posted so far.

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/MD5SUMS , http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/SHA1SUMS (pi 4 uses arm64 image)

Comment: Yes, and that image does not work with the 4 GB model (using full 4GB).

Comment: @guiverc I viewed the link you provided. The following one has not changed since the entry I encountered in August: 03254eadb82ba135add338b51ca2bd66c06aa621 *ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz Is there a link to a release schedule (however tentative that might be)? Regards.

Comment: That was a release folder, it contains the 19.10 release which will not change (ever) unless a new release gets spun (with different name ie. 19.10.1 having different checksums; that file name isn't changed so the checksums remain static! which applies any non-daily release; it was also spun in October so should differ to the alpha from August.

Comment: Dailies as described can be spun by a team member working on it; or on schedule which maybe more or less than once per day; daily meaning in that case interval (initiated by cron job viewable on launchpad).   I don't work on pi's so have taken no interest in their images, but likely useful - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/409/builds  (the 19.10.1 daily images for pi)

Comment: @guiverc, your explanations, clarifications and time are much appreciated by a novice like myself. Also, I sincerely appreciate the spirit of your replies since you don't work on RPi and yet fielded a series of elementary questions to help me understand. My learning never stops. Kind regards.